# saving values in array executing while loop

Tags: php, arrays

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
$sqldiag=$conn->query("select di_name from assi_diagnosis where di_id IN ($disp1$j)");
$i == "0";
$items = array();   
while($rsdiag=mysql_fetch_array($sqldiag))
{
echo $rsdiag['di_name'].">>";
$items[$i] = $rsdiag['di_name'];
print_r($items);
}
$i++;
```

Friends I would like to save values in array when processing an while loop . my expectation is when the first loop condition is executed $item[0] should contain all the resultset values of second while loop iteration for
 ex : (

```
$item[0] = {value1,value2,value3};
$item[1] = {value1,value2,value3};
$item[2] = {value1,value2,value3};
```

)

$item[**0**] is the value of first iteration 
values with in $item[0] are values of second while loop

Comment: Your first loop does't have opening / closing brackets and what is `$i == "0";` supposed to do? It is a conditional statement yet it's not inside an `if`.

Comment: You must change the logic of your script.. It is totally wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Keep $i++ inside loop.

```
while($rsdiag=mysql_fetch_array($sqldiag))
{
    echo $rsdiag['di_name'].">>";
    $items[$i] = $rsdiag['di_name'];
   $i++;// this line
}
print_r($items);// print here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$items = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
    $items[$i] = array();
    $sqldiag = $conn->query("select di_name from assi_diagnosis where di_id IN ($disp1$j)");
    while($rsdiag=mysql_fetch_array($sqldiag))
    {
        echo $rsdiag['di_name'].">>";
        array_push($items[$i], $rsdiag['di_name']);
        print_r($items);
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
print_r($items);
```

There were a couple of errors in your code.

- first `while` loop didn't have an opening nor closing bracket,
- you assigned value to `$i` using conditional operator `==` instead of `=`,
- each time second loop was ran it would override `$items[$i]` value instead of pushing to it as an array, use `array_push`, use if for all the `$rsdiag` values you want to assign,

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of little problems with your code which are fixed here

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {    
    $sqldiag=$conn->query("select di_name from assi_diagnosis where di_id IN ($disp1$j)");    
    $items = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($rsdiag=mysql_fetch_array($sqldiag))
    {
        echo $rsdiag['di_name'].">>";
        $items[$i] = $rsdiag['di_name'];
        print_r($items);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

issues:

```
$i == "0";
```

should be `$i = 0;` also

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
```

missing `{`